# Import mysql database in osx

Tags: mysql, windows, macos, import

I have a mysql dump generated from phpmyadmin in a windows environment,
when i try to import in osx (using mysql command line) there are encoding 
problems, the databases have the same encoding and collation.
I've also noticed that this problems occurs also when i try to import a 
diferent database from a unix virtual machine.
When i try to import the same databases in the Windows with the same commands everything is ok.

Anyone have a ideia about whats going on?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you show us some of the errors you are seeing?

Comment: The encoding problem are visible both in the phpmyadmin (but this also in 
Windows) and in the page (only on osx), for example "Afectos e RelaÃ§Ãµes" should be "Afectos e Relações".

I'm starting to think that the problem is with PDO (the php extension that i'm using to access the database) ...

Both the databases are with latin1_swedish_ci collation.

What do you think?

Answer (score 0):

Both databases have the following configuration:

character_set_client     | latin1
character_set_connection | latin1
character_set_database   | utf8
character_set_filesystem | binary
character_set_results    | latin1
character_set_server     | utf8
character_set_system     | utf8
character_sets_dir       | /usr/local/mysql-5.1.43-osx10.6-x86_64/share/charsets/